# what will happen when autopostback is true and when it is false?

Tags: asp.net

After a Postback does data go to server when it is true?  Please explain autopostback properties

Comment: Vote to close, duplicate of [Please help me understand AutoPostBack property of an ASP.NET control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409516/please-help-me-understand-autopostback-property-of-an-asp-net-control)

Answer (score 2):

AutoPostBack set to true will initiate a page postback (like clicking a button) whenever a server event for the control is fired. Server-side code tied to initiated control events will happen immediately (along with a full/partial page load).

AutoPostBack set to false will NOT initiate this and event code will not fire until another "posting-back" event fires.

Answer (score 0):

A simple google would have told you the answer to this:

Robbed from here as I thought someone else would be able to explain this better than me.

http://www.asp101.com/samples/autopostback_aspx.asp

> AutoPostBack is built into the
>   form-based server controls, and when
>   enabled, automatically posts the page
>   back to the server whenever the value
>   of the control in question is changed.
>   Because of the additional server
>   requests it causes, it's not something
>   you'll want to enable for all your
>   controls, but for things that affect
>   page display or change choices further
>   down the form, it can be really handy.
>   Not to mention the fact that it will
>   save you a lot of time and headaches
>   over trying to implement something
>   similar on your own. Not that it's
>   really all that complex to do on your
>   own if you're good with javascript,
>   but it's hard to get any simpler then
>   just setting AutoPostBack="True"

One thing to point out, this will only work when javascript is enabled, in the absense of javascript you will need to provide another mechanism to envoke the postback.